# How to show placeholder when we hover on input type text

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i want the placeholder to be visible when we hover on the textbox.

```
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter your name"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not possible to currently have the functionality built into the browsers, but with a small hack, it's possible:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: transparent;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: transparent;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: transparent;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: transparent;
}
:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #999;
}
:hover::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #999;
}
:hover:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: #999;
}
:hover:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" />
```

Also note the browser compatibilities.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did using javascript. Hope it's what you're looking for:

Suppose your textbox's id is set to "input", then

```
input = document.getElementById('input');

function ph () {
    input.setAttribute('placeholder','enter your name');
};

function phr () {
    input.setAttribute('placeholder', '');
};

input.addEventListener("mouseover", ph);
input.addEventListener("mouseout", phr);
```

Comment: JavaScript for this small thing is such an overkill for this. Just a heads up.

Comment: Yes, I see.
Just adding an alternative :)

Comment: Have a nice day! `:)`